# Localhost Access on Smartphone

Tags: mobile, proxy, localhost, local, smartphone

I'm developing a website that mostly will be used on smartphones. To check out my website I would like to see it on my smartphone without going live. 
How can I get access on the localhost address with my smartphone?

Answer (score 1):

If your phone and your PC were in the same network,
Check your IP address of your computer & Type the ip address on your mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

Get the ip address of your phone and allow that ip address on the firewall in your pc which is on same network